# method return result obtained in delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have the following method, which basically tries to get the user profile picture from facebook/twitter. The issue is that the result will be returned in a delegate, so therefore profilePicture results is obtained in the delegate called by these two methods. How do I deal with this?

```
- (NSString *) profilePicture
{
    NSString * result;
    if (facebook.isSessionValid){
        [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/picture"
                             andParams:nil
                         andHttpMethod:@"GET"
                           andDelegate:self];
    } else if ([_twitter isAuthorized]){
        [_twitter getUserInformationFor:[_twitter username]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want a method to be called in a delegate class when a picture is fetched? Then the class containing the function needs to have a reference to a delegate class. Then you simply call [delegate pictureFetched:result] instead of returning. The delegate needs to implement the function pictureFetched:

Comment: I basically want the profilePicture to return the URL of the image that I got from the delegate, is that clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the delegate to `self`. So you need to implement protocol methods that the facebook class specifies in this class.

In Facebook API, the protocol is named [`FBRequestDelegate`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) and the method you need to implement is `request:didLoad:`

Example: taken from [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/532/)

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSLog(@"Result of API call: %@", result);
}
```

Comment: I know about that... the question is that the result I got is obtained from the delegate, but I want to return it at the profilePicture function

Comment: @adit you can't do that. The facebook API call is asynchronous so the result has to be delivered via a callback. You can technically make a synchronous call to API but it will make your application hang for the time it take to return results.

Answer (score 0):

BY calling "[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/picture" andParams:nil andHttpMethod:@"GET" andDelegate:self];" you should be creating an object of FBRequest.

You could customize the FBRequest, Add a new typedef

```
typedef enum
{
    ...
    currentactionProfilePictureAccess,
    ...
}currentaction;

@interface FBRequest:<superclass>
{
    .....
    currentaction currentactiontype;
}
.....
@property(nonatiomic,asign) currentaction currentactiontype;
....
```

@end

also synthesize it in implementation.

And while creating the request specify the type of request(currentactiontype) you are doing.

When the result comes in "- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
 Check type of request and process.

```
if(request.currentactiontype==currentactionProfilePictureAccess)
{
    //call what ever you want.
}
```